# How can I position random objects on x,y,z using object pool?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts each one attached to another empty GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Pool
    {
        public string tag;
        public GameObject prefab;
        public int size;
    }

    #region Singleton

    public static ObjectPooler Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    #endregion

    public List<Pool> pools;
    public Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>> poolDictionary;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        poolDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>>();

        foreach(Pool pool in pools)
        {
            Queue<GameObject> objectPool = new Queue<GameObject>();

            for(int i = 0; i < pool.size; i++)
            {
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(pool.prefab);
                obj.SetActive(false);
                objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
            }

            poolDictionary.Add(pool.tag, objectPool);
        }
    }

    public GameObject SpawnFromPool(string tag, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        if(!poolDictionary.ContainsKey(tag))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Pool with tag " + tag + " doesn't exist.");
            return null;
        }

        GameObject objectToSpawn = poolDictionary[tag].Dequeue();

        objectToSpawn.SetActive(true);
        objectToSpawn.transform.position = position;
        objectToSpawn.transform.rotation = rotation;

        IPooledObject pooledObj = objectToSpawn.GetComponent<IPooledObject>();

        if(pooledObj != null)
        {
            pooledObj.OnObjectSpawn();
        }

        poolDictionary[tag].Enqueue(objectToSpawn);

        return objectToSpawn;
    }
}
```

And the second one and here I added inside the FixedUpdate the random part:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    ObjectPooler objectPooler;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        objectPooler = ObjectPooler.Instance;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var randp = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, 300), Random.Range(0, 300), Random.Range(0, 300));
        objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Cube", randp, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

It does what I want so far, But did I add the random part in the right script and place?

And how can I make that instead of generating nonstop random objects it will generate them only when I will change a Range slider of the size variable?

For example [Range(1,150])

And when I change the value it will add/remove the objects in the FixedUpdate? (It should be Update it's FixedUpdate since before that I used a Rigidbody but not now).

The idea is to either to change the size or if I set the size for example to 1000 and then to use a Range slider to change the number of using objects for example 445 or 500 or 1000.

And each time I change the size it will random the objects in other random positions. But once and not all the time like now in the FixedUpdate.

Each time changing the size change the objects positions randomly.
So if the size I changed it to 10 change the position of 10 objects randomly and use only these 10 objects. If I change the size to 700 then reposition randomly 700 objects and use the 700. (Not sure if it's right to say use or destroy).

UPDATE:

This is what I tried in the the first script I added the oldSize variable and the Range:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Pool
    {
        public string tag;
        public GameObject prefab;
        [Range(1, 150)]
        public int size;
        public int sizeOld;
    }

    #region Singleton

    public static ObjectPooler Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    #endregion

    public List<Pool> pools;
    public Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>> poolDictionary;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    { 
        poolDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>>();

        foreach(Pool pool in pools)
        {
            Queue<GameObject> objectPool = new Queue<GameObject>();

            for(int i = 0; i < pool.size; i++)
            {
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(pool.prefab);
                obj.SetActive(false);
                objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
            }

            poolDictionary.Add(pool.tag, objectPool);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }

    public GameObject SpawnFromPool(string tag, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        if(!poolDictionary.ContainsKey(tag))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Pool with tag " + tag + " doesn't exist.");
            return null;
        }

        GameObject objectToSpawn = poolDictionary[tag].Dequeue();

        objectToSpawn.SetActive(true);
        objectToSpawn.transform.position = position;
        objectToSpawn.transform.rotation = rotation;

        IPooledObject pooledObj = objectToSpawn.GetComponent<IPooledObject>();

        if(pooledObj != null)
        {
            pooledObj.OnObjectSpawn();
        }

        poolDictionary[tag].Enqueue(objectToSpawn);

        return objectToSpawn;
    }
}
```

And in the second script in the Start I'm using once the whole objects for example I start the game when the Range value is at 27 and then when changing the value I'm updating the oldSize:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    ObjectPooler objectPooler;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        objectPooler = ObjectPooler.Instance;

        foreach (ObjectPooler.Pool pool in objectPooler.pools)
        {
            var randp = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, 300), Random.Range(0, 300), Random.Range(0, 300));
            objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Cube", /*transform.position*/ randp, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        foreach (ObjectPooler.Pool pool in objectPooler.pools)
        {
            if (pool.size != pool.sizeOld)
            {
                int diff = pool.size - pool.sizeOld;
                pool.sizeOld = pool.size;

                // Spawn new diff number of objects if diff is positive
                var randp = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, 300), Random.Range(0, 300), Random.Range(0, 300));
                objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Cube", /*transform.position*/ randp, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
        //var randp = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, 300), Random.Range(0, 300), Random.Range(0, 300));
        //objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Cube", transform.position /*randp*/, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

But in fact the spawners in the Hierarhcy never changed there is all the time 27. If the Range is lower then 27 it will use less objects but if it's higher then 27 still in the hierarchy there will be only 27 spawners.

The size of spawners never change. And then when moving the Range left right it will fill the spawners use them until the end and that's it it will never change it will use them all but only 27.

Even if Range value is 150 for example still there are 27 spawners in the hierarhcy and in the game it self and not 150.

Answer (score 0):

> It does what I want so far, But did I add the random part in the right script and place ?

I don't know, if you ask me is 1 + 1 = 2, I can give you an answer.

> And how can I make that instead generating nonstop random objects it will generate them only when I will change a Range slider of the size variable ?

You need another size field:

```csharp
public class Pool
{
    public string tag;
    public GameObject prefab;
    [Range(1, 150)]
    public int size;
    private int sizeOld;
}
```

Then in the Update of FixedUpdate do a simple compare:

```csharp
void Update()
{
    foreach(Pool pool in pools)
    {
        if(pool.size != pool.sizeOld)
        {
            int diff = pool.size - pool.sizeOld;
            pool.sizeOld = pool.size;

            // Spawn new diff number of objects if diff is positive
        }
    }
}
```

> And when I change the value it will add/remove the objects in the FixedUpdate ?

Depends on where you call spawning method.

Comment: What do you mean by Update of FixedUpdate ? You mean in the second script the CubeSpawner and create there Update and put it in the Update ? And then to remove the FixedUpdate ? And I tried to put it in the FixedUpdate in the CubeSpawner script with references to the first script but it didn't work good.

Comment: If I start the game with 27 objects then changing the amount of objects the size and oldsize are the same value. And in the Hierarchy there are still only 27 spawners. Also in the game only 27. No matter if I'm changing it to  70 the size or change it to 5. There are still 27. And when running the game first time it's not using the whole 27 or if I start with 150 it's using only one the first spawner.

Comment: Maybe you could show me please the full code how it should look like ? Maybe I missed something ?

Comment: Use `Update` or `FixedUpdate` is on your decision I just write an example. Here is no full code, write spawning method by youself (at the place of the comment line).

Comment: _the size and oldsize are the same value_ ... as you see the code only changes `sizeOld` when they are not equal.

Comment: I understand now and did the changes. Please look at my question I updated with what I did and explained why and how it's not working good. If I start the Range with value 27 the game will start with one spawner in use !!! there are 27 in the Hierarchy but only only 1 in use instead all the 27. Second when changing the Range value for example to 150 in the hierarchy there are still only 27 spawners also in the game only 27 in use and not 150.

Comment: Here you say _spawner_, do you mean `CubeSpawner` or `Pool` or objects instantiated from Pool? before update I think the size value means the 3rd, the instantiated objects, is it right?